Как обратиться к удаленному сервису, который слушает только свою внутренюю сеть?
Я арендовал удаленный сервер с графическим ускорителем для экспериментов с LLM. К серверу имею доступ по ssh по некому адресу yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.
При получении сервера в аренду получаю инфу, что для изолированного доступа я могу обращаться к серверу еще по какому-то адресу yyy.yyy.yyy.zzz только с некоторого конкретного адреса  zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz. Что такое изолированный доступ - не понятно. Документации ноль, техподдержка ничего внятно объяснить не может. Но цены на GPU очень хорошие, и по ssh из командной строки все работает.
Внутри сервера ifconfig показывает свой адрес только во внутренней сети (192.168.xxx.xxx).
Хочу развернуть на сервере сервис ollama для работы с LLM извне внутренней сети арендованного сервера.
Инструкция по api сервиса ollama говорит, что обращаться к нему нужно так:
curl http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{
"model": "llama3",
"prompt": "Why is the sky blue?"
}'
Хочу обращаться к сервису со своего рабочего места так:
curl http://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:8181/api/generate -d '{
"model": "llama3",
"prompt": "Why is the sky blue?"
}'
где yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - адрес, по которому я могу обращаться к арендованному серверу по ssh
Насколько я понимаю, мне нужен ssh-туннель, но как его  в моем случае сделать я, читая всякие статьи, так и не понял. На stackoverflow есть похожий вопрос, но, кажется, про другое.
Пробовал так:

Поднял сервис ollama так, чтобы он слушал localhost:11434
Локально сервис работает.
На арендованном сервере ввел команду

ssh -R 8181:localhost:11434 user@yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
Выдает ошибку
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 8181:localhost:11434: Name or service not known
Как сделать правильно?


обращаться к нему нужно так:
curl http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{ "model": "llama3", "prompt": "Why is the sky blue?" }'


запустите socks5-прокси и обращайтесь ровно с теми же параметрами программы curl:
$ all_proxy=socks5://localhost:порт curl http://localhost:11434/api/generate ...

где порт - это тот самый порт, который вы указали опцией -D программы ssh:
$ ssh -D порт ...


Спасибо за ответ!
